# Let $G$ be a group, and suppose that $M$ and $N$ are normal subgroups of $G$. Prove that the intersection of $M$ and $N$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory

How do I find out the intersection of $M$ and $N$? I know $M$ and $N$ both contain the identity of $G$.

Besides, if I prove the intersection between $M$ and $N$ is a subgroup, how could I prove it is a normal subgroup as well?

Comment: You do not have to "find" the intersection of $M$ and $N$, you have to *prove* that the intersection of $M$ and $N$ is a subgroup of $G$. Write out the definition of "BLAH is a subgroup of $G$" and prove that each part of the definition holds when BLAH$= M \cap N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all note that $M,N$ subgroups.So $e\in M\cap N$

$\forall x,y \in M\cap N$ we have that $x,y\in M$ and $x,y \in N$ (since $x,y\in M \cap N$)

Then we see that $xy^{-1}\in M$ and $xy^{-1} \in N$ (since $ M $ and $ N$ subgroups)

So $xy^{-1} \in M\cap N$

Thus $M \cap N$ is subgroup

And if $x\in M\cap N$ then $\forall g\in G ,gxg^{-1}\in M$ and $gxg^{-1} \in N$ (since $ M $ and $ N$ are normal subgroups)

So $gxg^{-1}\in M\cap N$

Thus $M\cap N $ is normal subgroup of $G$